# How to convert IntelliJ android app project into android library project?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-library

I have an android app project that has code, assets, and layouts, that I'd like to make available in other apps.

The app project is in IntelliJ IDEA.

**Question 1)** How do I convert this project into an android library project?

**Question 2)** After converting, how do I import the library project into other app projects in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Evelyn check the docs:

**[Sharing Android Source Code and Resources Using Library Projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/sharing-android-source-code-and-resources-using-library-projects.html#d643385e134)**

**Converting an Application module into a Library module**

You can convert an Application module into a Library module by updating its Android facet.

1. Open the Project Structure dialog box by choosing File | Project Structure from the main menu.
2. Select Modules in the left pane. In the central pane, expand the node of the module that you want to turn into a Library module and click Android.
3. In the right-hand pane, select the Library module check box on top of the Android facet page.