# Import one android app into other app

Tags: java, android, module

I have implemented certain android app, this app has some several activities, views,fragments,google analytycs, crashlytics, gcm(cloud messaging, realm, retrofit, rx java and etc.).

I need to import this app as a module/library into other app in order to use the resources,activity,view and other classes of the imported app.

I think i should add is a module, and then add compile project('asdasd') to dependencies in the main :app module.

I'm not sure actually about the AndroidManifest.xml. Should i move all data from AndroidManifest.xml of the imported project to the main project? How to deal with google analytycs, gcm(it's connected to package name), plugins(fabric,realm,...)

What i want is to use the activities of the imported project in the main project. But what about Application class? Where it should be declared? as i use some instantiations when app starts.

Also i don't understand what will happen to imported project package name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert IntelliJ android app project into android library project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230015/how-to-convert-intellij-android-app-project-into-android-library-project)

Comment: @petey thanks, it's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to create `AAR` Android Archive file of your current project.** Basically .aar bundle is the binary distribution of an Android Library Project. An AAR is similar to a JAR file, but it can contain resources as well as compiled byte-code. A AAR file can be included in the build process of an Android application similar to a JAR file. Later you can add it as module dependency in your new project and you will able to reuse its components.

**You can also import it as module in your new project as you said**.

Query relating to GCM and other third party library merging will be taken care by Android Studio when manifest merger will happen.

Comment: ok. i got it. Anyway i can't use the Application class from the module, cause there will be other Application class in the main project. So i will need to copy the initialization to other Application file?

Comment: You can alway make your Application class that is in your app project extend from the Application class that is the library project.

Comment: @petey It's not that good, I added special class inside my library that initializes the library-app using 1 line of code in the main app Application class. the same approach as Realm.init(this)  inside onCreate method of Application.